# Where is the TestDriven.NET Options Pane?

Tags: testdriven.net

I am using TestDriven.NET 2.21 and I read on the creator's blog that there is now an options pane.  I am using Visual Studio 2008 Pro Edition.  The thing is, I can't find out how to access this options pane anywhere.  Where is it?

Comment: Maybe if your cognitive abilities were in the top 3% of the U.S. working population, you would have known this. Haw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> TestDriven.NET

Comment: nah.. i hunted around for it for a few minutes too.